# How to prove the power rule for derivative, Please give me the hints only, don't show the whole steps

Tags: calculus

Please only provide hints in proving the power rule for derivatives. Providing like a booster step might be helpful but blatantly showing the whole answer would not be educational

**my steps**
let h be the distance from the x value's x&A. Therefore we can conclude that $\frac{(f(x+h))(f(x))}{h}$ if we let $\frac{(f(a)-f(x))}{a-x}$, this means that $ \frac{d}{d(x)} =\frac{(f(x+h))(f(x))}{h}$

But the problem is that in numerous websites they utilized the binomial theorem,

First please explain why they are doing so

Second Please boost me into the correct place

Comment: Why are you multiplying f (x+h) to f (x)?  And what are you doing that has *anything* to do with the power fuctions rather than any other function.  As for why they use the binomial th, if you try to work this out the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a subtraction sign, a limit, and some
other details. Your later steps might or might not get messed up
because of that (depending on whether you remembered those things
when you needed them), but generally it's a good practice to be
as accurate as you can when writing out your formulas:

$$ 
\frac{d\color{red}{f(x)}}{dx} =
\color{red}{\lim_{h\to 0}}
\frac{(f(x+h))\color{red}{-}(f(x))}{h}
$$

The next thing is to show something a little more specific than
$f(x)$ for the function you are trying to differentiate.
Since you mentioned the power rule,
I suppose you mean to differentiate $f(x) = x^n$.
For simplicity (for now at least) let's assume $n$ is an integer.

So if $f(x) = x^n$, what is $f(x+h)$? Can you write it out using
$x$s and $h$s but no $f$s?
Can you write it in a form so that it makes sense to subtract $f(x)$
from it?
(This is when it pays to remember the hint about the
Binomial Theorem.)

If this is still giving you trouble, you could try choosing some literal value for $n$, for example try setting $n=2$.
That is, try to find the derivative of $f(x) = x^2$.
Then if you are able to do that, try $f(x) = x^3$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then,

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{a \to x} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{a \to x} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}.$$

Notice that we can factor the numerator as such,
$$x^n-a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+\dots +x^2a^{n-3}+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}).$$

See if you can verify the factorization by multiplying the right-hand side out (it helps to write the terms in two rows to see how they cancel out).

From here, I think you should be able to finish the rest of the proof.

Notice that this proof will not use the binomial theorem. The reason being is that usually the binomial theorem is used in the proof of the power rule when the alternative definition of the derivative is used:
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Answer (score 0):

" Therefore we can conclude that  $\frac {f(x+h)f (x)}{h}$ if we let $\frac {f (x)-f (a)}{x-a}$"

I haven't the slightest idea why you would think this.  It doesn't make any sense and it doesn't reflect any result that I know of.  Not only that but it doesn't really parse as proper English.  "Therefore we can conclude *what* about $ \frac {f(x+h)f (x)}{h} $?"   $\frac {f(x+h)f (x)}{h} $ isn't a statement.  It's just a single term.

For $f (x)=x^n $ then $f'(x)= \lim\frac {f (x+h) - f (x)}{h} = \lim\frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h} $.  So we need to expand out $(x+h)^n $.  To do that we need the binomial theorem.

$\lim\frac {(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\lim\frac {x^n+nhx^{nw1}+ {n \choose 2}h^2x^{n-2} +... +n*h^{n-1}+ h^n -x^n}{h}=\lim \frac {nhx^{n-1}+{n\choose 2}h^2x^{n-2}+.... + nh^{n-1}+h^n}{h} $

Can you take iron thete?